# Is it possible to make API only once per app in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to make a fetch api call only once for the whole app.

So is it good idea to use useEffect hook inside app.js, actually is it possible to do so.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to have an empty array as your second argument in useEffect.

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    **Your API call**
  }, []);

  return(**JSX you want to return**);
}
```

Note: this will call the API everytime the App component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve from what you wrote. If you are trying to get some kind of master-data which is necessary to run the app, you can definitely use an effect. Take care that it only runs once though.

Since I personally prefer to use redux, and I am very familiar with this pattern, I would use an action to fetch the data and initialise the app, using an async action library (thunk, saga, observables etc.). You'd still call `useEffect` in App.js to dispatch the initialise action, but the request would only be triggered if the data was not already present in the state.